# reposition the dragged div after dropping it

Tags: jquery-ui

is it possible to change the left position of a div after dropping it?
i'm trying to do that using this code but it's not working, can anybody help me...
thanks a million in advance :)

```
$(function () {
           $("#task_1").draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
           $("#Lina").droppable({
               drop: function (ev, ui) {
                   var pos = $("#task_1").position();
                   //                   kolla(pos.left);
                   if (pos.left < 0) {
                       alert(pos.left);
                       $("#task_1").position().left = 0;
                   }
                   else {
                       // do something else
                   }
               }
           });

       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick idea, have you tried:

```
 $("#task_1").css("left","0");
```

If the outer drop-area has relative positioning (not sure, have to check) that should work.

Basically, you want the dropped div to shift to the very left of the drop area, right?

### Update

You have it so that the position is changed when the condition is `pos < 0`. Since the div won't be in the drop-area if it's outside of it, I think you mean `pos > 0`. Also, why bother checking, if it's already 0, it just changes it to what it already is.

For instance:

```
$(function () {
           $("#task_1").draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
           $("#Lina").droppable({
               drop: function (ev, ui) {
                       this.position().left = 0;
               }
           });

       });
```

Notice I also made it "this" since you are changing the selector.